# JavaEE7 TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX when removing large data set

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7

when I try to remove a large dataset (>10k entities with each having collections of collections) I always get a transaction rollback after a certain amount of time.

Before the rollback happens, I get following WARN on the server console:

```
2015-12-08 16:39:15,143 INFO  [stdout] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-6) Remove ticket 18979
2015-12-08 16:39:15,500 INFO  [stdout] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-6) Remove ticket 18982
2015-12-08 16:39:16,149 INFO  [stdout] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-6) Remove ticket 18986

2015-12-08 16:39:17,567 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff55d63658:62b71159:5666952b:6abd in state  RUN
2015-12-08 16:39:17,569 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff55d63658:62b71159:5666952b:6abd invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2015-12-08 16:39:17,569 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff55d63658:62b71159:5666952b:6abd aborting with 1 threads active!
2015-12-08 16:39:17,910 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
2015-12-08 16:39:17,911 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) IJ030020: Detected queued threads during cleanup from: Transaction Reaper Worker 0: java.lang.Throwable: Detected queued threads during cleanup from: Transaction Reaper Worker 0
        at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1552)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.SecurityActions.getStackTrace(SecurityActions.java:81)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.cleanup(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:302)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.returnConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:692)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.returnConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:646)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.returnConnection(AbstractPool.java:852)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.returnManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:681)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion(TxConnectionListener.java:1199)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.transaction.TransactionSynchronizer.invokeAfter(TransactionSynchronizer.java:459)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.transaction.TransactionSynchronizer.afterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizer.java:395)
        at org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.afterCompletion(JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.java:163)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:96)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:545)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:476)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.cancel(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:130)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.cancel(AtomicAction.java:215)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.doCancellations(TransactionReaper.java:381)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.coordinator.ReaperWorkerThread.run(ReaperWorkerThread.java:78)
```

I'm using Java EE 7 on Wildfly 9.0.2 with JPA, Hibernate on MySQL Server.

In general the remove of each entity is very slow (as the tree of each is very deep) but I really would like to use the power of JPA and not writing own queries with taking care of all the bothering child removal.

The bean that is calling the remove action is stateless. The request itself is coming from a REST call.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: The remove call is done within a ExecutorManagedService Thread.

Comment: apparently someone decided to configure a transaction timeout value (which is not necessarily a bad idea). Check the server settings: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/beanp.html

Comment: Is this the same for wildfly?
I don't want to change the TA timeout globally as this would affect all my transactions. Furthermore I don't know how long my long lasting task takes to finish. It could be 1 hour but also a day.

Comment: I don't know what to answer to that. Is what the same in Wildfly?

Comment: The link shows settings for Glassfish. I'm using WF. The point is, that I don't want to set the global timeout for all transactions to more than a day. My single task could take a day, but all my others are less than 5 minutes.

Comment: ... wow, I'm sorry. I don't know how I could have misread that so badly. With Bean Managed Transactions you have more fine-grained control over the timeout of a specific transaction so you could consider using that for your day-job. Or if atomicity is not a requirement, you can split the long-running transaction up into batches of short transactions, say processing 5000 records per transaction.